# Cycling pipelining

Tags: f#, pipeline

I have a matrix: Array2D and a function

```
let DivideAndSubstract value index (matrix: float[,]) = 
    //something that returns a matrix
```

so I need to apply this function n times to my matrix like that:

```
matrix  
|> DivideAndSubstract matrix.[0,0] 0  
|> DivideAndSubstract matrix.[1,1] 1  
|> DivideAndSubstract matrix.[2,2] 2  
....  
|> DivideAndSubstract matrix.[n,n] n
```

where n = Array2D.length1 matrix - 1
How can I implement this pipelining?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the top of my head:

```
{0..n} |> Seq.fold (fun M k -> DivideAndSubtract matrix.[k,k] k M) matrix
```

*Edit: a few more words won't hurt the answer:*

Using a fold is a typical pattern of 'apply F to x and apply F to the result and apply F to that result ... until I don't need to apply F again'. The imperative version of the line above would be

```
let mutable M = matrix
for k in 0..n do
    M <- DivideAndSubtract matrix.[k,k] k M
M
```

Inside the fold, M denotes the intermediate result at each step. It may take a while to grasp how folds work, but once you do, they're pretty powerful.

Comment: The cycle should look like `M <- DivideAndSubtract M.[k,k] k M`

Comment: Right. Took a shower and realized that fold should be   `|> List.fold (fun M k -> DivideAndSubtract M.[k,k] k M) matrix` Now it works, Thanks

Comment: You could also replace `[0..n] |> List.fold` by `{0..n} |> Seq.fold` so there is no creation of a list.

Comment: OK, but that's not what you've written in your example. Because values in F# are immutable, each occurrence of 'matrix' in your chained pipe is the same matrix as the one you started with. To get what you want use `List.fold (fun M k -> DivideAndSubtract M.[k,k] k M)`

Comment: @Stringer Bell: you're right, no throw away intermediate list is needed. I'll update.